# How to do a Select and Update query on one SQL string?

Tags: c#, sql, select, sql-update

I would like to do something like this on my MySQL Database.

`SELECT * FROM itemsordered WHERE purchaseOrder_ID = '@purchaseorderID';`

then retreive the `stock_ID` on the itemsOrdered database and the number of items that were ordered.

`string stockID = (dr["stock_ID"].ToString())`
`string restockQuantity = (dr["quantity"].ToString())`

then use them to replenish the On-Hand quantity in the stocksDB

`UPDATE stocksdb SET quantity = @restockQuantity WHERE stock_ID = @stockID`

is there a more simple way to do this?

`itemsordered` database columns 
`itemsOrdered_ID` `purchaseORder_ID` `stock_ID` `quantity` `status` `datereceived`

`stocksdb` database columns 
`stock_ID` `name` `onHandQuantity` `pricePerPiece` `dateUpdated`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE stocksdb s
    INNER JOIN itemsordered i ON i.stock_ID = s.stock_ID
    SET quantity = i.quantity WHERE i.purchaseOrder_ID = '@purchaseorderID';
```

Comment: May I be able to add s.quantity data to the i.quantity data? like this: `SET s.quantity = (s.quantity+i.quantity) WHERE i.purchaseOrder_ID ='@purchaseOrder_ID'`

Comment: by the way.. will this update all the `s.quantity` from the `i.quantity`. I mean, will this update all the stocks ordered for replenishment?

Comment: Are there multiple stocksdb rows for each itemsordered row? Or the other way around?

Comment: It is the other way around sir. The itemsordered Database will have recurring stock_ID and purchaseOrder_ID values

Comment: no the itemsOrdered_ID is the unique ID in the itemsordered table. The purchaseOrder_ID is a foreign key from the purchaseOrder table. It is like a reservoir of the items that were ordered on a Purchase Order

Comment: In that case, yes, this query will update all the stocksdb rows that this purchase order modified. You should add the `(s.quantity+i.quantity)` part, though.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are a more simple way. You can `UPDATE` with `JOIN` like so:

```
UPDATE stocksdb s
INNER JOIN itemsordered i ON s.stock_ID = i.stockID
SET s.quantity = i.onHand
WHERE i.purchaseOrder_ID = '@purchaseorderID';
```

Comment: Oh no sorry, I am not trying to do a Count(*). I would like to copy the number of restockquantity to the onHand quantity on stocksdb

Comment: @JohnErnestGuadalupe - Sorry for that, Can you please post the two tables' strucutres?

Comment: posted it sir. Will the said SQL string, update all the stocks ordered for replenishment?

Answer (score 1):

you can do an inner join in a update statement.

```
update stocksdb a inner join itemsordered b on a.stock_ID = b.stock_ID
set a.quantity = b.quantity
purchaseOrder_ID = '@purchaseorderID';
```

sql statement is untested, but i think you get the idea

cheers